# Ansible file doesn't exist for S3 but exists for copy

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I'm trying to migrate my config files from a folder on an ec2 instance to an s3 bucket. We use ansible to update changes to these config files every deploy and I'm having issues getting ansible to work with s3. Here's the old ansible section for updating the config files to ec2.

```
- name: Install config files
  copy: src="{{core_repo}}/config/{{item.path}}" dest=/opt/company/config owner=user group=user mode=0644 directory_mode=0755
  with_items: config_files
  tags:
    - deploy
```

nothing crazy, just copy a bunch of files with certain permissions. Ansible's copy has no problem finding the files described in config_files.

Here's my new ansible section for updating the config files to s3.

```
- name: Install config files
  s3: bucket=company-config object="/{{item.path}}" src="{{core_repo}}/config/{{item.path}}" mode=put aws_access_key=access aws_secret_key=secret
  with_items: config_files
  tags:
    - deploy
```

As you can see, I haven't changed the way in which I reference the files themselves. However, I'm now receiving an error for each of these files:

```
failed: [ip] => (item={'path': 'application.properties'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"path": "application.properties"}}
msg: Local object for PUT does not exist
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Or any suggestions as to how I might fix this issue? I'm using ansible-playbook 1.9.4.

Comment: Are you copying the files to S3 from your Ansible host or from the EC2 instance?

Comment: @PasiH I'm copying the files to S3 from my Ansible host.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to copy the files to S3 from your EC2 instance and the files have been copied to the EC2 instance using *Install config files* task, then the files reside in `/opt/company/config` on the EC2 instance.

`src` attribute should then be changed to `"/opt/company/config/{{item.path}}"` and s3 module be called as follows:

```
- name: Install config files
  s3: bucket=company-config object="/{{item.path}}" src="/opt/company/config/{{item.path}}" mode=put aws_access_key=access aws_secret_key=secret
  with_items: config_files
  tags:
    - deploy
```

If you wanted to copy the files directly from your Ansible host to S3 then you'd call s3 module using local_action. The respective task is:

```
- name: Install config files
  become: no
  local_action: s3 bucket=company-config object="/{{item.path}}" src="{{core_repo}}/config/{{item.path}}" mode=put aws_access_key=access aws_secret_key=secret
  with_items: config_files
  tags:
    - deploy
```

Comment: My intention is the latter. Prepending the s3 command with local_action throws me a different error:

failed: [ip -> 127.0.0.1] => (item={'path': 'application.properties'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"path": "application.properties"}, "parsed": false}
[sudo via ansible, key=key] password:

Comment: It looks like you are running the playbook with `sudo`. Try disabling `sudo` in `Install config files` task (the answer updated).